# Managing a ModalStack in Xamarin Forms with FreshMVVM

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

Using

- FreshMVVM
- Xamarin Forms 4.4 on iOS and Android

There are many questions on how to clean up a modal stack in Xamarin Forms and from those I have:

```cs
var numModals = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.ModalStack.Count;

// To prevent the page from being temporarily visible as each Modal above it is Popped, set the Opacity to 0
for (int currModal = 0; currModal < numModals; currModal++)
{
    NavigationPage navigationPage = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.ModalStack[(numModals - currModal) - 1] as NavigationPage;
    navigationPage.Opacity = 0;
}

for (int currModal = 0; currModal < numModals; currModal++)
{
    await this.CoreMethods.PopPageModel(null, true, false);
}
```

Whilst this does work it adds a dependency on `Application.Current` to my ViewModel. Seeing as we are using FreshMVVM I am looking for an approach that works better with that and removes my Application.Curent code.

Custom navigation services with IFreshNavigationService are the only thing that jumps out at me however the examples I see for those are either

1. Login Page navigation and MainPage navigation boundary
2. Tabbed View

An example page flow I have is

1. HomePage (non modal)
2. ValueHistoryPage (non modal)
3. ConfigureValueDevicePage (**modal**)
4. ChooseValueDeviceModelPage (**modal**)
5. ConnectValueDevicePage (**modal**)

At this point the user can decide they have configured their ValueDevice but don't want to use it yet so go back to ValueHistoryPage which would mean closing down all the modals so ValueHistoryPage is now the TopMost or to start a new navigation set that goes to CaptureFromValueDevicePage (**modal**) AND closes down the previous set of three Modals (ConfigureValueDevicePage, ChooseValueDeviceModelPage and ConnectValueDevicePage )

Would the first set of Modals be in one custom IFreshNavigationService and potentially CaptureFromValueDevicePage in a separate IFreshNavigationService ?

Are there any examples of IFreshNavigationService that are not tabbed views or Login related?